# Android Socket: Send Data Repeatedly with a Fixed Time Interval

Tags: android, sockets

I have a code that sends data on click. However, I want to send data repeatedly with a fixed time interval.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new `PrintWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, or `OutputStreamWriter` per message. They should all exist for the life of the socket. And you shouldn't execute networking code on the event thread.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also tried with AsyncTask (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309994/android-socket-read-continuous-data/22310320?noredirect=1#22310320), but for some reason, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread with a while loop and a Thread.sleep() call.
This post has all the code you need:
[How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Comment: I change the code, but for reason it shows null pointer exception; here is the updated code:

  final Runnable r = new Runnable()
  {
      public void run() 
      {
    try {
     String str = "test";
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
       new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
       true);
     out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } 
      }
  };

Comment: Unfortunately the code is hard to read and I don't think I'm seeing all of it. Maybe you could paste your code in https://gist.github.com/ or pastebin.com and add a link here. Also it helps to provide the stacktrace error.

Comment: @MKS You can see for yourself that posting code in comments is futile. It is quite illegible. If you have a new question, post it, with that code, and the stack trace *and the code concerned* and an indication of which line throws the exception. There's nothing there that throws a `NullPointerException` unless `socket` is null, but you should have been able to work that out for yourself.